# How do i return a string using regex to exclude a part from string to be matched

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-matching, regex-negation

I am trying to match a list of strings to a regex as follows -

```
regex.IsMatch(displayName)
```

but step two of my check needs to make sure that if there is any text contained within brackets in `displayName` it should not return a match.

For ex.

if `regex` is looking for a string that contains "Muds"

so if my first string is

"My name is Muds" -- it should return a match (True).

"My name is **(** Muds contained **)** " -- it should return **NO** match (False).

"My name is **(** **{** Muds **}** **)** " -- it should return **NO** match (False).

so essentially, the above string is reduced to **"My name is"** and contents within brackets are excluded.
so IsMatch statement is then reduced to -

```
regex.IsMatch("My name is")
```

I made a regex that looks for contents within the bracket

```
Regex excludingRegex = "\s?(?:\(.+\)|\[.+\]|<.+>|{.+})\s?"
```

lets call above as `excluding regex`

So i want to do something like

regex.IsMatch(**ExcludingRegex.Replace(displayName,"")**)

In short i want to exclude contents within brackets to be matched with the first Regex

I have seen many examples about **Negative Lookahead** and excuding context from regex but i am not able to get it right for my case.

Any pointers will be great.

Comment: Why not check if string contains  `{` or `}`? text.Contains("{")

Comment: its not as simple, may be i could not explain properly but we need to exclude all brackets and contents within

Comment: @Muds what should happens when input is "My { name is ..."?

Comment: though its logically not possible but users can create anything so i would consider unclosed bracket as a typos and return A MATCH

Comment: @Muds ok, we a getting closer. And what you say about "My ( name } is"? Should it also return match?

Comment: regex.IsMatch(XXXX) .. i want this XXXX to be everything excluding contents within any brackets. so in the example that you gave, regex.IsMatch should receive "My is" and since regex is looking for Muds it should return no match.

Comment: The content with in brackets can appear more than one time?

Comment: it  can, there can be more than one bracket set like
My name is (Muds) i also write as {Muds Mals) .. so we need to exclude both texts Muds as well as Muds Mals

Comment: Try [`!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"[[({<][^[({<]*Muds[^])}>]*[])}>]")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5b%28%7b%3c%5d%5b%5e%5b%28%7b%3c%5d*Muds%5b%5e%5d%29%7d%3e%5d*%5b%5d%29%7d%3e%5d&i=%22My+name+is+Muds%22%0d%0a%0d%0a%22My+name+is+%28+Muds+contained+%29+%22%0d%0a%0d%0a%22My+name+is+%28+%7b+Muds+%7d+%29+%22). It is the opposite to what you need, hence `!` before `Regex.IsMatch`.

Comment: ^^ pardon my regex illiteracy but how do i use this in my context wherein i need to exclude a part of string and not look for a match literally

Comment: regex is universe evil, dont ever use it

Comment: haha evil ? it comes smashing when you are crying for performance with millions of strings in your hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather simple - use a lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\([^()]*\)).+
```

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^                # start of the string
(?!.*\([^()]*\)) # neg. lookahead making sure there's nothing between ( and )
.+               # match the line
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/v9KAbr/1/).

Comment: Thanks jan, witha little tweak i got an idea to make it work. just one thing i wanted to ask why did you exclude inner () by using "[^()]" any specific reason ?

Comment: @Muds: No particular reason but you'd need a recusrive approach for nested parentheses.

Comment: thats what i thought, recursion in regEx, learning new bits every day. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi here is a code I created in a console application. Here Im using the function regex.split to split the string using a regular expression(the reg exp checks where is a string inside {}) and checking the even items in the array I can check if I found the string mud and display where it was found. The items in the odds are the ones found inside the {} in the string been checked.

You can download the code [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZvJH3X3rnshl6vuUBTBEjZGIEEzKjJmb)

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 string input = "My name is ( { Muds } ) My name is MUDS ( { Juan } ) My name is ( { Ortiz Mud } ) otra cosa por aca {juan} pero pues aqui mud {yani}";
            string pattern = @"\{(.*?)\}"; 

            string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

            for(int i= 0; i <= substrings.Length; i ++)
            {
                if(i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (substrings[i].ToLower().Contains("mud"))
                    {
                        Console.Write(string.Format("This string has mud outside of brackets. Found in string: {0}", substrings[i].ToString()));
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
            }



            Console.Read();

        }
```

Comment: thanks for your attempt but i was looking for an answer that totally works on regex